# update a cell in a excel sheet using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to search for a word in a row from a spreadsheet and update another cell in the same row with a different value. For example, I have the data like this. I need to search for the person "Smith" from the below spreadsheet and update the value of the 'Status' column from 'Enabled' to 'Disabled' for that row.

```
"Region","Zone","Customer","Process","Status"
"TEST","East","Smith","HR","Disabled"
"TEST","East","Allen","Finance","Enabled"
"TEST","East","Jake","Payroll","Enabled"
```

I tried regex and few other functions before posting the question. But I can't get them to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, yes. That's the scripting language chosen by our organization.

Comment: I don't see how PowerShell can't do this. It basically just imports a CSV and update column based on string search, output a new CSV at last. I will put an answer if there is none.

Comment: Is it a `.xlsx` or `.csv`? This will determine if it can be done natively or if you need to import a module designed to manipulate excel files.

Answer (score 11):

It's very easy to use Excel with PowerShell:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

$excelFile = 'C:\test\testsheet.xlsx' 

$searchFor            = 'Smith'

$excel                = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible        = $true
$excel.ScreenUpdating = $true

$workbook  = $excel.Workbooks.Open( $excelFile ,$null, $false )

$ws        = $workbook.WorkSheets.item(1) 

[void]$ws.Activate()

$searchRange  = $ws.UsedRange

$searchResult = $searchRange.Find( $searchFor, [System.Type]::Missing, [System.Type]::Missing, 
                                               [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt]::xlWhole, 
                                               [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder]::xlByColumns, 
                                               [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection]::xlNext )

while( $searchResult ) {

    $row = $searchResult.Row
    $col = $searchResult.Column

    $ws.Cells( $row, $col + 2 ).Value2 = 'Disabled'
    $searchResult = $searchRange.FindNext( $searchResult )

    if( $searchResult -and $searchResult.Row -le $row ) {
        break
    }
}

[void]$workbook.Save()
[void]$workbook.Close()
[void]$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I realized the excel option works only when the MS Excel is installed on the machine where the script is being executed and we are not allowed to install MS Office tools on the servers.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the below script.

```
$TGTSERVER = "testservwc01"

$name = "ORATDLLSTR"
        $input = Invoke-Command -ComputerName "$TGTSERVER" -ScriptBlock {Import-Csv 'C:\test.csv'}
        $value = "Disabled"
        $Output = foreach ($i in $input) { 
            if ($i.Process_Instance -match "$name") {$i.Status = "$value"} $i } 

        $OutArray = $Output | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, RunspaceId, PSShowComputerName
        $OutArray | Invoke-Command -ComputerName "$TGTSERVER" -ScriptBlock {Export-Csv 'C:\test.csv' -NoTypeInformation}

        if ( $LastExitCode -ge 1) 
              {
                    Write-Warning -Message "$Computer : Disable Step failed"
                    exit 1
        }
```

However the script fails with exit code 1 even though it updates the csv file with the right value on the remote server.

Answer (score -1):

I have found solution which meet my needs... using Powershell
Not the issue mentioned as in topic.. but overall module have a lot of options which might help modify Excel File using PowerShell

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWriteExcel/0.1.15
https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteExcel/blob/master/Examples/Run-Example-FindReplace.ps1

```
Install-Module -Name PSWriteExcel

Import-Module PSWriteExcel -Force
$FilePath = "D:\Excel_test.xlsx"
$FilePathOutput = "D:\Excel_test1.xlsx"
Find-ExcelDocumentText -FilePath $FilePath -Find 'evotec' -Replace -ReplaceWith 'somethingelse' -FilePathTarget $FilePathOutput -OpenWorkBook -Regex -Suppress $true
```